# PostgreSQL 8.4 no levenshtein fuzzymatching?

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, postgresql-8.4, postgresql-extensions

I'm using debian squeeze package, it says function does not exist?

Answer (score 7):

You have to install the additional module [**`fuzzystrmatch`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html).

In PostgreSQL 9.1 or later, simply run [`CREATE EXTENSION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
```

In PostgreSQL 8.4 on Debian Squeeze, you would run as OS `postgres` matching the DB superuser `postgres` (so with peer authentication without PW) the SQL script provided by the package `postgresql-contrib-8.4` (install that if you haven't already):

```
sudo -u postgres psql mydb -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/fuzzystrmatch.sql
```

About `CREATE EXTENSION`:

- [Do I need to execute "create extension pgcrypto" everytime?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197167/do-i-need-to-execute-create-extension-pgcrypto-everytime/197558#197558)