# Do I need to execute "create extension pgcrypto" everytime?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, read-only-database, pgcrypto

I have used `crypt()` in one of my functions to hash user password. But what I observed the next day I started my pc that the same thing failed as cryptographic functions became unavailable upon restart. It showed message like functions `gen_salt()` / `crypt()` is unknown or not defined. I executed `create extension pgcrypto;` once and it started working.

How to handle this in prod environment? Is there a way to make this module permanently available in db even if db is restarted?

Or do I have to instruct server manager to run this command in case they required to restart db server?

Or **can** I write this statement in functions itself so that it will create the extension every time before using cryptographic functions?

Moreover, we are using a read-replica of db, where it did not allowed to execute this "create extension" statement as there is read permission only. So how to make this cryptographic functions available in such read-only environment?

Comment: Welcome to the site, could you update your crypt() function. whatever you have written for better understanding.

Comment: Pardon, I didnt get it. If you're asking for short description, then it could be : How to retain cryptographic functions available on db restart event ? And how to execute the "create extension pgcrypto" in readonly permission.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**`pgcrypto`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html) is a regular Postgres extension. You have to install it **once per database** (not per DB cluster like you may have been assuming) to use it. Installation is *permanent*, surviving DB restarts.

**If** you want every ***new*** database in the same DB cluster to have it pre-installed, you can install it to the default template database `template1` by connecting to it and installing it normally. *Or* install it in any other database and use *that* as template with:

```
CREATE DATABASE new_db TEMPLATE my_template;
```

See:

- [Creating UUID extension as the non super privileged user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15535/creating-uuid-extension-as-the-non-super-privileged-user/15539#15539)

One other thing that can go wrong: the `search_path`. See:

- [Is it recommended to install extensions into pg_catalog schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107389/is-it-recommended-to-install-extensions-into-pg-catalog-schema/107418#107418)
- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)

But if that was your problem you'd get warnings when trying to install the same extension a second time.

The only other exotic explanation I can think of: your DB might have been restored to a previous state. But you would certainly know of that, wouldn't you?

Or did you just connect to a different database by mistake? The "read replica" you mentioned?

> how to make this cryptographic functions available in such read-only environment?

If it's not replicated by your replication solution, you have to install it manually *once.*

Comment: "once per database" is really the answer for me