# Postgres trigram match acting strange for specific characters

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, pattern-matching

I'm using pg_trgm to run a query, but I'm getting a lot of 1 matches when searching with a symbol difference. I have the following query:

```
SELECT my_column, similarity('$ Hello', my_column) AS sml
FROM my_table
WHERE my_column % '$ Hello'
ORDER BY sml DESC, my_column;
```

In `my_table`, I have the following:

```
- Hello
? Hello
| Hello
$ Hello
! Hello
!? Hello
```

They all return with a similarity match of 1. Do I need to escape the '$' or something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other answers clarified that trigram similarity is based on alphanumeric characters only. That's why all your examples match 100 %.

You may still be able to make use of a trigram GiST or GIN index *and* establish your desired sort order with additional `ORDER BY` expressions. For your demonstrated case:

```
SELECT my_column, similarity('$ Hello', my_column) AS sml
FROM   my_table
WHERE  my_column % '$ Hello'
ORDER  BY sml DESC
        , my_column <> '$ Hello'       -- !
        , my_column;
```

The boolean expression `my_column <> '$ Hello'` evaluates to `FALSE`, `TRUE`, or `NULL` - with *this* sort order. So the exact match (considering *all* characters) comes first. And this query can still use a trigram index. A trigram GiST index would (still) even support a **"nearest neighbor"** (KNN) search with `LIMIT`. Related:

- [Search in 300 million addresses with pg_trgm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44838192/939860)
- [Optimizing a postgres similarity query (pg_trgm + gin index)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43867449/939860)

You can do more, depends on your exact use case and requirements. Example:

```
...
ORDER  BY sml DESC
        , my_column <> '$ Hello'
        , my_column !~ '\$ Hello'            -- note $ escaped with \$
        , levenshtein(my_column , '$ Hello')
        , my_column;
```

Within the same trigram similarity, this sorts exact matches first, then strings *containing* the exact phrase. And within each subgroup matches the shorter Levenshtein distance first. Alphabetical as final tiebreaker. Related:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)
- [PostgreSQL 8.4 no levenshtein fuzzymatching?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33137/postgresql-8-4-no-levenshtein-fuzzymatching/33138#33138)
- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45741630/939860)

Last but not least, you tagged **[full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html)**. But your example is based on trigram similarity (provided by the additional module [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html)), which is a largely different concept with completely separate infrastructure and operators. You may want actual full text search instead (and phrase search with that?):

- [How to search hyphenated words in PostgreSQL full text search?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204588/how-to-search-hyphenated-words-in-postgresql-full-text-search/204601#204601)

But punctuation characters are considered noise and stripped in FTS all the same. Same "problem". `ts_debug()` shows how your text search configuration classifies identified tokens in a given string (`simple` configuration in the example).

```
SELECT * FROM ts_debug('simple', '? Hello %&/( 123');
```

It starts with the "default" parser (currently the only one), parsing all these as noise to begin with ...

Comment: What a fantastic answer with a variety of solutions to the problem I was facing. Thank you for your time! Most appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT show_trgm('$ Hello');

            show_trgm            
---------------------------------
 {"  h"," he",ell,hel,llo,"lo "}
(1 row)

SELECT show_trgm('- Hello');

            show_trgm            
---------------------------------
 {"  h"," he",ell,hel,llo,"lo "}
(1 row)
```

All non-alphanumeric characters are stripped from a string before the trigrams are calculated.

That's why the strings have similarity 1.

You cannot use trigram indexes for searching for symbols.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) has it in its first sentence (emphasis mine):

> The `pg_trgm` module provides functions and operators for determining the similarity of **alphanumeric text** based on trigram matching

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring punctuation is how pg_trgm works, as documented.

If you are feeling adventurous, you can remove the line `#define KEEPONLYALNUM` from "contrib/pg_trgm/trgm.h", recompile and reinstall.

This will silently corrupt any existing pg_trgm indexes you have, you will need to reindex them.